# Bootstrap CSS is not loading on example page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am experimenting with bootstrap css but it just isn't loading on my browser, I've even published the page on my server, It doesn't even render the css styles. Now other example pages load fine on my browser. Just the ones I download locally are giving me an error.

Here's what I've tried out so far:

1. Validated the HTML to see if I'm making some sort of syntax error but thats not the case. It came clean as a whistle.
2. Downloaded the bootstrap.css and locally referenced it in the html just in case it was something with my server fetching the file but that didn't worked either.
3. Lastly, I thought that this might had something to do with my text editor's  text encoding or perhaps the end-of-line character incompatibility so I went to codeply.com and executed the damn thing in their online editor and good lord, it didn't worked there.

To clarify further, this is how the page is supposed to look like
[image]

against how It does look like
[image]

I can see that the css styles are partially applied as the page is not showing default html fonts and styles. I even tried changing permissions of the index.html file to 777 in case that was causing trouble but all in vain so far.

[Here's a link to my raw html in codeply.com](https://www.codeply.com/p/87Q3YE86yZ)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='site-wrapper'>
        <div class='site-wrapper-inner'>
            <div class='cover-container'>
                <div class='masthead clearfix'>
                    <div class='inner'>
                        <h3 class='masthead-brand'> NileSoft </h3>
                        <nav>
                            <ul class='nav masthead-nav'>
                                <li>Our Clients</li>
                                <li>Our Services</li>
                                <li>Contact</li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inner cover">
                        <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
                        <p class="lead">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn more</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is js/bootstrap.main.js?? file ? Can you share code ??

Comment: bootstrap css is working fine .

Comment: You should load bootstrap javascript file after jquery file that is at bottom. `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Might try writing the script tag such as this: 
`<script src="./js/bootstrap.main.js"></script>`

Also, the same for the link tags which includes your bootstrap file locally:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Also, the preferred order for CSS and JS files are as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.css" />

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    ...


   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <!-- Bootstrap JS File -->
   <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <!-- Custom JS File -->
   <script src="./js/custom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Script imported at the bottom has a http, it might have got blocked by your browser. Also writing   `<script src="js/bootstrap.main.js"></script>` might not work in codeply. Also, try importing other js files after standard libraries like jquery.

Answer (score 0):

To get Bootstrap into your page, simply paste the code below into the `<head>` section of your template.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```